# Can I ever get Magic Paint as a reward from solving a Puzzle Box?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza, streetpass-mansion-monster-manor

Some vistors in Monstor Manor will offer me a puzzle box to solve. Since I've already solved all 50 boxes at one point or another, I generally skip these. But I could always use more Magic Paint. What are the possible rewards from puzzle boxes, and is Magic Paint one of them?